# Quick Smoke effect not showing on other device (shared blender file)

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have a project in blender 3.1 that has a quick smoke effect. Everything works perfectly on my pc. But when i shared my project with a friend, the quick smoke effect just stopped working. Nothing is showing in his viewport or render. How do i fix this so my friend can work in the project en render it? ( I don't know if it helps but i already used: external data -> automatically pack resources )

Comment: Have you baked the smoke on your pc and not transferred the baked data?

Comment: yes, i baked it on my pc but how do you transfer baked data?

Comment: Open the *Physics* tab of the *Smoke Domain* object and have a look at the *Fluid > Cache* settings. There is a directory path defined where Blender saves the baked data. Normally, some subdirectories and many files are created in it. Zip the cache main folder and give it to your friend. On the other pc, unzip it, and make sure the path is correct. Then it should work. If everything fails, you still can use the "Free Data" and "Bake" buttons to bake it again on the other pc.